# Problems with displaying the content of a text file in a tpl using the bottle framwork

Tags: python, return, text-files, bottle, static-files

Im trying to display the content of a text file in a template without any luck so far. This is
my code so far:

```
@route('/show_article/<filename>')
def show_article(filename):
    stat_art=static_file(filename, root="articles")

    return template('show_article', stat_art=stat_art)
```

And this is the paragraph in my template to display the content of the file

```
<p>
    {{stat_art}}
</p>
```

I know that I could just return the static_file() but I will need to design the page with
some css and stuff later.

Thanks in advance and sorry for if my english is not correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misunderstood what static_file does.

Luckily, the fix is simple: just read the file yourself and pass its contents to the template, like so:

```
@route('/show_article/<filename>')
def show_article(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:  # <-- you'll need the correct path here, possibly including "articles"
        stat_art = f.read()

    return template('show_article', stat_art=stat_art)
```

That should do the trick.

[Btw, nice first question!]